# How can I get a list of possible transitions for a given role in a state machine workflow?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, workflow-foundation

On a given state machine workflow, how do we find out the possible transitions for a given role. In my scenario, only certain roles have the permission to perform certain activities. I have to get that list. The helper class `StateMachineWorkflowInstance` isn't helpful here as it just returns all the possible transitions, ignoring the role of the actor.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Socratees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no straight forward way to do this. I wrote this method based roughly on the solution at [Ruurd Boeke's blog](http://www.sitechno.com/Blog/HowToFindOutWhatWorkflowStateTransitionsArePossibleForAGivenRole.aspx) . I'm getting the list of possible events, and then looking if they can be executed by the user role. It's a work around, but still works fine.

```
public string[] GetTransistions(string strUser)
{
    string[] strRoles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(strUser);
    List<string> strActivity = new List<string>();
    ReadOnlyCollection<WorkflowQueueInfo> queues = workflowInstance.GetWorkflowQueueData();
    foreach (WorkflowQueueInfo info in queues)
    {
        if (!info.QueueName.Equals("SetStateQueue"))
        {
            foreach (string subscribedActivity in info.SubscribedActivityNames)
            {
                HandleExternalEventActivity heea = workflowInstance.GetWorkflowDefinition().GetActivityByName(subscribedActivity) as HandleExternalEventActivity;

                #region check roles
                if (heea.Roles != null)
                {
                    foreach (WorkflowRole workflowRole in heea.Roles)
                    {
                        foreach (string strRole in strRoles)
                        {
                            if (workflowRole.Name.Equals(strRole))
                            {
                                strActivity.Add(heea.EventName);
                                //permissionLog += workflowRole.Name + " can perform " + heea.EventName + " Activity. ";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                #endregion
            }
        }
    }
    return strActivity.ToArray();
}
```